# Random class not found errors in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload, laravel-artisan

We get random errors in php (windows 7 with xampp):

PHP Fatal error:  Class [NAME OF MY CLASS] not found

The class exists and the HTTP requests for the same call works 99% of the time, but sometimes we get this error. Why?

**UPDATE:**

I already run composer dump-autoload and the mapping is in the autoload_psr4.php file.

BUT, I found there's also a mapping that starts with the same path, but with an invalid folder, for example:

My class is: `Path/SubPath/ClassX`

In autoload_psr4.php i have (in this same order):

```
'Path\\SubPath\\' => array($vendorDir . '/company/project/src'),

'Path\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
```

The problem here is: in the second entry, the `$baseDir . /src` folder doesn't exists. Can this explain why I get random errors? (By sometimes getting the second mapping instead of the first one)

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Can you share the autoload configuration in `composer.json`, please?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to run : `composer dump-autoload`.

> composer dump-autoload regenerates the
>   list of all classes that need to be included in the project
>   (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside
>   your project

Then run the following three commands:

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

This will clear the current compiled files, update the classes it needs and then write them back out so you don't have to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a laravel specific issue. Try this commands:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Is it possible to have more details about this specific issue you're talking about. Because I want to understand why I got this randomly and why these commands will solves the problem.

Comment: I think it's just a very old (> 2 years) bug in artisan. It happens when you upgrade to the next version of laravel. The artisan command is screwing up services.json.

Comment: I don't use Laravel, so this doesn't appear to be Laravel-specific. I don't use a static autoloader during development, so that doesn't explain it either. I have this issue randomly on pages that trigger multiple requests - so it appears there's some sort of race-condition somewhere, possibly in the autoloader or PHP itself. (I don't know how an outdated autoloader would explain random classes randomly failing to load anyhow - if that were the cause, the same class would fail to load all the time.)